# Stored procedure for insert query in sqlplus not working properly

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I am trying to execute the following `insert` query within a `stored procedure` to further call in a `java' class -

```
SQL> create or replace procedure admininsert(ID IN varchar2, UEMAIL IN varchar2, PASSWORD IN varchar2, FLAG IN number)
as
begin
insert into user values(ID, UEMAIL, PASSWORD, FLAG);
end;
/
Procedure created.
```

However, the issue I have is that, when I try to run the same by using the following -

```
exec admininsert("ABC","DEF","GHIJKLM",2);
```

I get the following error -

```
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-06550: line 1, column 20:
PLS-00201: identifier 'ABC' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

Am I executing the procedure in a right way? If not so, then how should I go along with the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For string literals, you want single quotes `'` around your values.

```
exec admininsert('ABC','DEF','GHIJKLM',2);
```

Comment: thanks a ton bruh, helped alot cheers